# What should be returned from an API endpoint that accepts a list of resource IDs but one of the passed IDs does not exist

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I have an API endpoint that returns multiple resources which can be filtered by a URL parameter. An example is below and all of the IDs are in the correct format.

```
http://localhost:8000/products?ids=1,2,3,4,5
```

However, the resource with the ID of `4` does not exists (in the database for example). I could do the following:

- Return only 4 product resources.
- Return only 4 resources but also include a couple more fields such as `requestedCount` and `returnedCount`.
- Return an error with an appropriate HTTP status code.

Are any of the above viable options or is there a better solution? On the frontend, I will display a list of resources only if all of the requested resources were found so need to know if they all were returned or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether the partial content is satisfiable for the clients. If not, then better to return a 4xx header without content.

If you want to serve partial content, then you can use the 206 partial content with range headers or the 207 multi-status on these scenarios. The multi-status might be the better option.

Here is an example about the multi-status:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "results": [
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/1",
      "status": 200
    },
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/2",
      "status": 200
    },
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/3",
      "status": 400
    },
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/4",
      "status": 403
    }
}
```

https://evertpot.com/http/207-multi-status

With the 206 you need a custom ranging solution with the range headers. It can be done, but typically it is used for byte ranges, not for ids.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/products
Range: ids=1,2,3,4,5

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Range: ids=1,4,5

{
  "results": [
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/1"
    },
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/4"
    },
    {
      "href": "/batch/5/item/5"
    }
}
```

https://www.belugacdn.com/blog/cdn/206-partial-content-error/

Though you can return `416 Range Not Satisfiable` in these cases too.